# SugarCRM 7 executing custom script in EditView/Create Record

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Recently upgraded to Sugar version 7.1.5 from 6.4. In 6.4 we had option to include the custom java script code and file in editviewdefs.php however in new version there is no way to do that.

After going through the documentation, I found "record.php" and "record.js" files in base where we can edit the code for "DetailView" only and not for editview.

Just looking for additional help in SO apart from Sugar forums due to the severity of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Record (record.js) view is kind of similar to the old Detail View, but with inline editing.

The Create view, the same layout as Record view but with all editable fields, is kind of similar to Edit View but is actually called create-actions.js.

So you can extend these views for each module you require to add custom js code, though due to the big differences in the DOM you may need to rewrite much of your code to fit the new architecture.

Comment: Where should we need to put the create-actions.js. The record.js file we put in following path.custom/modules/TR_TripReport/clients/base/views/record/record.js

Comment: create-actions.js would follow the same format: custom/modules/TR_TripReport/clients/base/views/create-actions/create-actions.js